# HTML codes won't work in OpenCart shipping Method label

Tags: twig, opencart, shipping-method

I want to have custom code in my shipping Method label but by default, OpenCart stops the code I think for security reasons with adding quote before and after my code, so it won't work and show correctly.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Also is there any security issues that I might face by doing this? (since it's a checkbox I personally think it's safe)

Thank you guys please check this image I have sent you.
[image: OpecCart shipping_method file]

Best regards

Comment: Due to your screenshot - you only removed a comment section. Can you show the code (view and model)? Did you clear a twig cache in OC dashboard?

Comment: Hi,
Yes I have clear the cache I don't know how to solve my problem if I change quote.code to code function won't work and NO method label show up.

Comment: Can you show your custom code (view and model)? You can add it to your question.

Comment: What kind or information (code) do you want to place in label? I wish to help you, but there is to few information to operate with

Comment: <div><p>Shipping fee <span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">The part I what to be different</span>Shipping fee</p></div>
or
<p>Shipping fee <span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">The part I what to be different</span>Shipping fee</p>
and
Shipping fee <span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">The part I what to be different</span>Shipping fee
I have tried both of them
I Can't add photo in comment directly so check this link.
https://imgur.com/Zm4BJFF
Also I use X-Shipping free

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of an all controller, from your last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a template issue. Go to **catalog/model/extension/shipping/xshippingpro.php** There you will find

```
$quote_data['xshippingpro'.$tab_id] = array(
```

And inside of it

```
'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($cost, $xshippingpro['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')),$currency_code)
```

You can add your custom code here, only here, if you want to modify only **X Shipping**.

You can change `title` to

```
'text'         => '<span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">' . $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($cost, $xshippingpro['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')),$currency_code) . '</span>'
```

**UPDATED**

To set custom text in title in the same document find

```
'title'        => $xshippingpro['name'][$language_id],
```

change to

```
'title'        => 'custom text <span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">' . $xshippingpro['name'][$language_id] . '</span>custom text',
```

**UPDATE 2**

To use custom html like in you example (overwrite security), change

```
'title'        => $xshippingpro['name'][$language_id],
```

into

```
'title'        => html_entity_decode($xshippingpro['name'][$language_id], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this will change the price part.
My problem is with the title of the shipping method, I want to be able to use custom code in the title field of X-Shipping like this.
Shipping fee <span style="color: #d1383d; font-weight: bold;">The part I what to be different</span>Shipping fee
https://imgur.com/DhXHnAa

Comment: Updated an answer. Try UPDATE 2, and you will be able to insert html to title.

Comment: Thank you for the second update did solve the problem. but are there any security flaws or problems that might be happening now?
(I know that it won't get any entries data from the user but I'm wondering why developers wrote the code like this?)
https://imgur.com/JBrpGaG

Comment: There is no security flaws in this situation. HTML filter is everywhere on OC, but in this case you exactly know what you are doing and no one stranger has access to admin panel, so you are safe.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the time you spent on my problem.
Thank you so much